# finding top N frequent words in each cluster using R

Tags: r, nlp, data-science, data-analysis, topic-modeling

I have topic vectors as my dataset, where each row represents a different topic (described by different weights on all 441 words in the columns). I'm running it through k-means to see which topics are selected together. For each group algorithm selects,I want to see top words that appear across topics to see how the topics are similar.

[Here is subset of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAWZ2.png)

I have little to no knowledge of text analysis but this what I have so far:

```
topic <- read.csv("topicVecs.csv", stringAsFactors = FALSE)

library(ggpubr)
library(factoextra)
library(NbClust)

set.seed(123)
res.km <- kmeans(scale(topic[,-5]),5, nstart = 25)
res.km$cluster
fviz_cluster(res.km, data = topic[, -5],
   palette = c ("#2e9fdf", "#00afbb","#e7b800", "#fc0439", "#ff5733"),
   geom = "point",
   elipse.type = "convex",
   ggtheme = theme_bw()
)

k <- 5
```

I thought I could start from 5 clusters. Not sure how to go about it from here.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].